# git workflow: local and remote branches

Tags: git, repository, workflow

I have a quick question regarding local and remote branches in git. Is it common practice for your local branches to be mirrored on your remote repository? It seems to me as though this would make sense, so what reasons would there be for having different branch structures on your local/remote repositories?

Thanks!

Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personnaly I do so, so its easier to merge them later.
Depends also of your repository server, if it has server-side merging capabilities or not.

But essentially, it depends of who is managing the projects and if you are alone or not pushing commits on the server and if so if these branches are worth being seen and used.

Comment: ...How does git uphold the structure of your branches if they do not match from local to remote?

Comment: When you push you can tell what to push and where.
For example :
`push origin mylocalbranch:myremotebranch`